# Regex only allow letters and some characters

Tags: regex

I am attempting to create a regex that only allows letters upper or lowercase, and the characters of space, '-', ',' '.', '(', and ')'.  This is what I have so far but for some reason it is still letting me enter numbers

```
^[a-zA-Z -,.()]*$
```

any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Escape characters that are regex tokens : .()

Comment: @ Mathias E: Inside a character group, you don't have to escape all regex tokens.

Answer (score 19):

`-` is special in character class. It is used to define a range as you've done with `a-z`.

To match a literal `-` you need to either escape it or place it such that it'll not function as range operator:

```
^[a-zA-Z \-,.()]*$
         ^^ escaping \
```

or

```
^[-a-zA-Z ,.()]*$
  ^ placing it at the beginning.
```

or

```
^[a-zA-Z -,.()-]*$
              ^ placing it at the end.
```

and interestingly

```
^[a-z-A-Z -,.()]*$
     ^ placing in the middle of two ranges.
```

In the final case `-` is place between `a-z` and `A-Z` since both the characters surrounding the `-`(the one which we want to treat literally) that is `z` and `A` are already involved in ranges, the `-` is treated literally again.

Of all the mentioned methods, the *escaping method is recommended* as it makes your code easier to read and understand. Anyone seeing the `\` would expect that an escape is intended. Placing the `-` at the beginning(end) will create problems if you later add a character before(after) it in the character class without escaping the `-` thus forming a range.

Comment: Thank's, Work perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

Well, there is an issue in that `-,` is being interpreted as a range, like `a-z`, allowing all characters from space to comma. Escape that and at least some of the bugs should be fixed.

```
^[a-zA-Z \-,.()]*$
```

Strictly speaking, you should probably also escape the `.` and `()`, too, since those have special meaning in regular expressions. The Javascript regex engine (where I was testing) seems to interpret them literally within a `[]` context, anyway, but it's always far better to be explicit.

```
^[a-zA-Z \-,\.\(\)]*$
```

However, this still shouldn't be allowing `0-9` digits, so your actual code that *uses* this regular expression probably has an issue, as well.

Comment: No need to escape `.`, `(`, `)` inside the character class. In character classes only `]` and `\‍` as well as `-` and `^` (both depending on the position) have a special meaning.

Answer (score 2):

The  `-,` in `[a-zA-Z -,.()]` describes a range from   (0x20) to `,` (0x2C). And that is equivalent to `[ !"#$%'()*+,]`. You should either escape the `-` or place it somewhere else where it is not interpreted as a range indicator.

But that’s not the cause of this issue as the digits are from 0x30 to 0x39.

Answer (score 0):

I tried that with javascript and it works fine. The others are correct, though. If in javascript, check if everything works fine or else the check will not happen at all.